# Can I create varying number of component based on length of array?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Suppose I want to create number of components based on the length of the array which props from the parent component.

```
<template>
  <------here is some logic to toggle "ComponentName"------->
 <keep-alive>
      <component v-bind:is="ComponentName"></component>
 </keep-alive>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  methods: {
  createComponents: function(){
     for (let i = 0; i < this.MyArray.length;i++){
        ----Create component with name "Component-i" and based on the content in MyArray----
}
}
}
  data(){
      return{
          MyArray: this.$route.params.MyArray,
          ComponentName: '',
      },
  }
}
</script>
```

Is there are any way to do so? I mean, to create dynamic number of component?

Comment: You could create a dynamic number of components using a v-for loop, but I'm not sure what you mean by 'based on content in MyArray'. Could you give an example of the sort of data the array would hold?

Comment: @OmarSiddiqui actually i am doing a page for data filling. Let say we have have unknown number of customer, then i want to create a component to let them fill in their name, id …etc. And my array entry correspond to each customer, and each entry is essential a dictionary to store different value. So what i  want to do is switching the customer will give you a blank component to fill in data. But if you switch back to some customer you have done, the data you filled won’t lost. So my component is actually from a single template, but for each customer, my program create a new instance for it.